# Pipe/send command to process running on nohup that accepts input from STDIN

Tags: pipe, nohup

I have a program that I run using `nohup program &`. This program accepts input from `STDIN`. Is there any way to send text to the `STDIN` of a program that is running via `nohup`?

This is on FreeBSD running bash. I would like to see how this is done on linux as well.

Comment: Linux (which)? Unix (which)? OS X? AmigaOS? It probably wouldn't hurt to say which shell. Bash? Bourne? Korn? C? Z? Fish?

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nohup` runs the program with standard input redirected from `/dev/null` (assuming that you didn't redirect the `nohup` command itself). So no, you can't send input to this program.

If you want to send input to the program, redirect the input when you start it:

```
nohup program <input-file.txt &  # input from a file
nohup data-producer | nohup program &  # input from another program
mkfifo program.pipe; nohup program <program.pipe &  # input from a named pipe, feed it what you want later
```

(Actually, it may be possible to reconnect the program's standard input to another source, by using `ptrace`, i.e. a debugger or other hack. This could crash the program if it keeps track where its input is from. See [How can I pause up a running process over ssh, disown it, associate it to a new screen shell and unpause it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034/885); there are other questions on the SE network on this topic.)

Comment: Won't data-producer get killed?

Comment: @wliao Indeed. I've added `nohup` in front of it as well, thanks.